# how to find focal length?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cordova, camera

Ii,
I need to find the focal length of my phone camera in reactjs app. I'm using cordova-camera-plugin for open the camera but I couldn't find a way to access to the camera's information, any solutions?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to stack overflow, please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), what have your tried here, have you got any code to show? What errors are you receiving?

Comment: You should check `Native Modules` section on React Native documentation page

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?